# Conversion error. parseInt seems to not be converting my text values

Tags: java

Help would be greatly appreciated. I keep getting an error message every time I try to run the following code:

```
        bt36.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String amt=scr.getText();
            int intAmt = Integer.parseInt(amt);
            String bal=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
            int intBal = Integer.parseInt(bal);
            int remBal;

            if ((intBal-intAmt)<0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insuffiecient funds, try a lower amount");   
            }
            else{
                remBal=intBal-intAmt;
                data3.setText("Withdrawl succesful, remaining balance: "+remBal);
            }
        }
    });
```

Exact error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error lies within this block? The only thing that stands out so far is `txt` and `txt2` both being used - is that intentional?

Comment: yes using txt and txt2 is intentional. I swapped the code for the place where the error actually lies. Got any suggestions now?

Comment: Where is the variable **a** declared and filled? Are you sure **bal** contains anything? Is there a Dollar sign, a comma, a space or any non-numerical character within the string passed to the **Integer.parseInt()** method. If the a string passed to the **Integer.parseInt()** method contains any alpha characters (non-numerical) or is a null or null String (**""**) then the method will throw this exception. I suspect **bal** contains a null string (**""**) as the exception indicates. Your code needs to test for these situations. `if (bal.matches("\\d+)) { .... }`

Comment: Sorry...it could be: `int intBal = bal.matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(bal) : 0;`. This example uses a [Ternary Operator](https://www.sitepoint.com/java-ternary-operator/).

Comment: oh, okay. Thanks DevilsHnd